# How can I replace static ObservableCollection so it accesable on all windows in the MVVM way

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

Atm I got a class(somerandomclasss) with a static ObservableCollection:

```
public static ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> thepeoplelist = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModem>();
```

However, I am converting my project to MVVM and of course this is not a good way to fill all my itemscontrols(listviews mainly) I got multiple windows that use this source in this way.

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lsvallthepeople.ItemSource = somerandomclasss.thepeoplelist;
}
```

The listview displays then all the people with the info.
However this isn t the MVVM way I bet, and I haven't found a good way to work without a public static ObservableCollection, however there is a window where you got a listview where you can edit the persons, they get updated in the SQL database and in the PersonViewModel (that got the INotifyPropertyChanged).

If you need any more information feel free to ask ofc :).

Comment: It is difficult to determine what you are asking.  I suggest editing your post to contain a well-defined question and clearly communicate what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @j0rd4n I think he's asking how to bind to a static collection, since in MVVM you want to use the XAML bindings to bind the `ItemsSource` instead of setting it in the code-behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a `Static` binding to bind your `ItemsSource` instead of setting it in your code-behind manually

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={
    x:Static local:somerandomclasss.thepeoplelist}}" ... />
```

or expose a property which returns the collection from your ViewModel and bind to that property

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> PersonList
    {
        get { return somerandomclasss.thepeoplelist; }
    }

    ...
}

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" ... />
```

Comment: But then for every window/usercontrol that wants to use(bind) to the somerandomclasss.thepeoplelist it will have to have a "MyViewModel" Varient for its datacontext ? btw your first answer is just the same as I do but then without the codebehind. But that is a wrong way of using a list in MVVM?(Or am I wrong here :)?)

Comment: @Maximc The difference between `setting` and `binding` a property is that binding a property means the application will go to the binding's source to get the property, while setting it means the property is set to a copy of the value. Your code example sets the value, which means the UI is working with a copy of the application data and not the actual data.

Comment: I don't think it breaks the MVVM design pattern to bind to a static property, however I do consider it breaking the pattern to set a property to a static value in the code-behind because then your UI code is directly referencing and manipulating application objects.

Comment: but according to j0rd4n(in an other answer) I ll have to use the basic person model instead of the PersonViewModel, then I won t have any Viewmodel at all if I display my items with a ObservableCollection<Person> public static?(So I ll skip ViewModel It will be my Data(Basic class) straight to the View?

Comment: @Maximc You can do it either way. I don't have a problem with binding to a plain data `Model`, however if I need additional functionality, such as a `SaveCommand`, or if the class grows beyond a simple data model, then I will create a `ViewModel` for the class. If you're interested, I have a [simple MVVM example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) posted on my blog

Answer (score 3):

I believe what your are asking is, "What is the best way to share a list of items across multiple views in MVVM?" so I'll answer the question that way.

Let's assume you have a service that provides a way to get the list of people.  You called it a "PersonViewModel", but you might be confusing a domain entity with a ViewModel.  In MVVM, you have a view which represents the UI control or screen.  Then you have a ViewModel which binds to the view and joins the View to the data/domain model.  The ViewModel can have a number of public properties that the View will bind to including methods that call services to populate those properties from your data model.  In your case, I would have a View + ViewModel and the ViewModel has an ObservableCollection property of class "Person".

The following code is a paraphrase of what it might actually look like.  Not everything is implemented.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        this.LoadPeople();
    }

    private void LoadPeople()
    {
        this.People.Clear();
        // Have your logic here that loads the people collection
    }
}
```

As far as managing a single list, I recommend caching the people collection in some kind of static class or singleton that is accessible to your view models.  Then the LoadPeople method above can just pull from the cache.  You can even lazy-load the cache so that it doesn't make the service request until its first access.

```
internal static class SystemContext
{
    private static ObservableCollection<Person> _people = null;
    public static ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            if( _people == null )
            {
                _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
                // load the list here from a service or something
            }

            return _people;
        }
    }
}
```

So in your ViewModel, LoadPeople would then look something like this:

```
public void LoadPeople()
{
    this.People.Clear();

    foreach( Person person in SystemContext.People )
    {
        this.People.Add( person );
    }
}
```

Your UI will then look something like this:

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource={Binding Path=People, Mode=OneWay}
    SelectedItem={Binding Path=SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}
    >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PersonName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateOfBirth, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <!-- etc -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You got my question right. So I ll add to the loadpeople: this.People = somerandomclasss.thepeoplelist;? btw I got the PersonViewModel because Person has a date of the people their birth, but I want to display the age(an iteger rather then a data) So that is why I got a PersonViewModel that loads the Person class?

Comment: Just because Person has some attributes you want to show on the UI doesn't mean it has to be a ViewModel.  Think of your ViewModel as a container of all the properties and list of properties you want to bind your UI to.  Once you bound the UI to the ViewModel collections and properties, you can reference any sub-property directly in XAML.

Comment: The problem is my Person class got a property Dateofbirth, but I don t want to display it, I want to display the age(integer). So I made a PersonViewModel and added a property intage { get return somefunctionthatcalculated the age on person.Dateofbirth }}, or should I make that method for calculating their age just in the person class, or make a converter for it?

Comment: See my updated post.  You don't need a separate view model.  Just because the property is on your Person object doesn't mean it will automatically show up on the UI.  You have to pick and choose which properties are bound (see my updated example in XAML).  Just add a new property to your Person class for an age integer and bind to that instead of DateOfBirth.

Comment: @JordanParmer What if LoadPeople is based on a user defined? For Eg: IT should load according to the user inputs. Where can be the parameter passed? and which VM should be binded to the View?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have this as a service or repository that is injected into each view model (as an abstraction) that requires the list.

As you want to populate this list just once, you could either do this in the constructor of the service/repository implementation or use a caching technique in the services `GetList` method.

As you always want to pass the same instance to each view model, you should use either a singleton pattern, or register the abstraction (e.g. `IPeopleRepository`) against a particular instance if using an IoC container.

As this would be a service/repository, you should return a type that isn't dependent on the presentation technology, i.e. an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IList<T>`, and use this to create your observable collections in each view model.