# Notify ViewModel on change in static Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm designing a `LogManager` class to handle all my logs in my application, in the form of `LogMessage` objects. They are saved in an `ObservableCollection` in the class. The `LogManager` itself is static for access in every part of my program.

Now I want to make a `View` that can display the `ObservableCollection` of `LogMessages`, but I can't wrap my head around how I could notify the `ViewModel` that a new `LogMessage` has been added...

I tried implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but since the class is static this is not possible.

PS: I'm using the MVVM-Light toolkit for my application

Comment: I am pretty sure you can bind static properties. AFAIK, `{ Binding  Source = { x:Static YourClass.Property...` should work. I remember I read something similar when was playing with wpf, not sure btw

Comment: Yes, I was right: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9500648/1283847 It's a duplicate, btw.

Comment: @PLB: That could work, however I would rather have the collection in my `ViewModel` since I want to be able store it in an alternative `ObservableCollection` so I can clear the logs in the view, but not in the `LogManager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider the responsibilities of you `LogManager`. Does it really need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

You can use a `StaticResource` in your XAML for the `LogManager` or provide a property for it inside the View's ViewModel.

ViewModel:

```
//Placeholder class
public static class LogManager
{
    public static ObservableCollection<LogMessage> Messages { get; }
}

public class LogMessage
{
    public string Text { get; set; } 
}

public class LogManagerViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<LogMessage> Messages { get { return LogManager.Messages; } }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" />
```

That said I would find it advisable to consider using the builtin dependency injection capabilities of MvvmLight and making the `LogManager` non static.

Comment: I was doing exactly the same thing and I thought it didn't work since I didn't see anything in my ListBox, then I read your answer and I realize I didn't set the DisplayMemberPath property.. Stupid me! Thanks for making me realize, this could've definitely too me a while to find out myself